# Implementing a canvas in the body editor?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes when I want to ask a question it is somehow difficult to explain what I want exactly (especially whent it is a TIKZ issue).

As I am lazy to open something like paint, draw a picture, make a shot or use the file and upload it here, it may could be easier to directly implement a very basic canvas tool in the question editor. There I can directly draw a very basic picture which can explain my issue better than words (also the possibility to edit the picture afterwards).

I don't really know how complex this would be to implement and, of course, if it is a dumb or a good idea.

Comment: I don't know. Usually the assumption is that you post a question if you have an issue that you could not resolve on your own. Frankly, this request seems a tiny bit like you want to have maximal convenience when you are asking others to convert your drawings or ideas to Ti*k*Z code. You do have the possibility to upload things here, and I do not think it is that inconvenient to mark the screenshot of what you already have in such a way that it is clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay I see your point. It was not my intention to request a feature that people can ask something like: 'please translate my attached drawing in tikz' Currently I have just a very simple question and for this a liitle canvas tool would be helpful because i am not able to create a single part in a picture using tikz in the correct way

Comment: This is all fine. However, I think it is fair to say that your question in the present form can be interpreted in the way I do in my above comment. So you may benefit from making your question more specific, and perhaps also leave the "I am lazy" part out. A significant number of users may take this as a request to pave the path for even more "Do-that-for-me" type questions.

Comment: one other consideration is that such a request can't be applied to this site alone.  it would have to be implemented for all of stackexchange (and stackoverflow).  i suspect that would not be high on the priority list for the folks that manage these sites.

Comment: You want an answer from a user, hopefully with working code, maybe explanations and a screenshot of the result. That does take time. You want to have a canvas because making a screenshot is too inconvenient?

Comment: apart from the other comments the network backend is shared across the stackexchange network, so you would need to raise a feature request on the main network meta not here in the tex specific one.

Answer (score 6):

There's no need for this since there exists a number of default tools on most operating systems already providing this functionality:

- Windows: MS Paint (distributed by default)
- Mac: [PaintBrush](https://paintbrush.sourceforge.io/)
- Linux: [Pinta](https://pinta-project.com/pintaproject/pinta/)

I'm sure there are others as well. I use [FS Capture](https://www.portablefreeware.com/index.php?id=775) on Windows for capturing screen shots and editing/annotating them. If you don't want to work on something from your computer, you can use a free online image editor like [Pixlr](//pixlr.com/editor) (similar to Adobe Photoshop).

Note that you don't have to work with *files* when trying to post an image. You can *copy* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>) an image (like a screen shot), open the Insert an image dialog and *paste* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>) them as well.

Comment: Just to add: on a Mac you can take a screen shot of an area by just pressing `command+shift+4`. The selection will be put on your `Desktop` folder. If you click on the picture button when writing a question or answer and then on the area of the window that pops up, a file dialog opens up from which you can select the screen shot. Provided you sort by date, it will be the first item of the file list.

Comment: On Windows you can also use the built-in snipping tool to take screen shots of areas and annotate them: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13776/windows-use-snipping-tool-to-capture-screenshots

Comment: On Linux you can use Shutter (which has an Edit option, to edit the image).